# Integrating a solid using cartesian, cylindrical and spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

[image: problem]

> The region $W$ is the cone shown below (see image).
>
> The angle at the vertex is $π/3$, and the top is flat and at a height of $7\sqrt{3}$.
> Write the limits of integration for $\int_W dV$ in the following coordinates (do not reduce the domain of integration by taking advantage of symmetry):

#### Progress

As seen in the image, the ones highlighted in red are those I cannot figure out. I'm not sure if I have some fundamental misconceptions that allows me to derive some of the boundaries but not others, but if someone can kindly explain how to find those values in red, I would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this your homework or something? There is ""(1 pt)"" attached to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The cross-sectional radius of the cone increases linearly with $z$, so the lower limit of $z$ also increases linearly.  So $1/7$th of the way up, the lower $z$ limit needs to be $\sqrt{3}$.  From your bounds on $x$ and $y$, $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \sqrt{2}$ at $z=1$, so the limits of $z$ are $\left(\sqrt{3/2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)$ to $7\sqrt{3}.$

For the cylindrical coordinates, it's much the same.  Replace $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ with $r$.  (You should have $r$ as the integrand instead of $\rho$.)

For the spherical coordinates, the $\rho$ dependence is with $\phi$ only.  At $\phi=0$, $\rho = 7\sqrt{3}$, while at $\phi=\pi/6$, $\rho=7\sqrt{3}/\cos(\pi/6).$  So your upper limit is $7\sqrt{3}/\cos\phi$.

The integrand is determined from the spherical volume element, which is

$$dV = \rho^2 \sin \theta\; d\rho\; d\theta\; d\phi.$$